# What is the difference between case object defined in scala repl and sbt console?

Tags: scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

When I declare case object in SBT Console, it creates module

```
scala> case object A
defined module A
```

And when I define it in Scala REPL,  it creates object

```
scala> case object A
defined object A
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11266474/5599298

Comment: it's always `defined object` for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in using the Scala REPL or SBT Console.
The difference you are seeing is probably because of Scala Version. 
Cross check the Scala Version on Scala REPL and SBT Console it will be different as in Scala with version `10` series `case object` is defined as `module` but after Scala version `11` series they show `object`.

You can check the Scala version when you are opening the SBT Console or Scala REPL

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192398/what-is-the-difference-of-running-scala-and-sbt-console).

Hope this clears your doubt.

Thanks